# Ullman’s Subgraph Isomorphism Algorithm

Tags: matlab, graph, isomorphism

Could somebody give me a working Ullman's graph isomorphism problem implementation in MATLAB, or link to it. Or if you have at least in C so I would try to implement it in MATLAB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i'm lookign for it too. I've been loking in the web but with no luck so far, but i've found this:
[Algorithm](http://adriann.github.io/Ullman%20subgraph%20isomorphism.html), where the algorithm is explained.

On another hand, i found this:

```
def search(graph,subgraph,assignments,possible_assignments):
update_possible_assignments(graph,subgraph,possible_assignments)

i=len(assignments)

# Make sure that every edge between assigned vertices in the subgraph is also an
# edge in the graph.
for edge in subgraph.edges:
 if edge.first<i and edge.second<i:
  if not graph.has_edge(assignments[edge.first],assignments[edge.second]):
    return False

# If all the vertices in the subgraph are assigned, then we are done.
if i==subgraph.n_vertices:
 return True

 for j in possible_assignments[i]:
  if j not in assignments:
   assignments.append(j)

  # Create a new set of possible assignments, where graph node j is the only 
  # possibility for the assignment of subgraph node i.
  new_possible_assignments = deep_copy(possible_assignments)
  new_possible_assignments[i] = [j]

  if search(graph,subgraph,assignments,new_possible_assignments):
    return True

  assignments.pop()
  possible_assignments[i].remove(j)
  update_possible_assignments(graph,subgraph,possible_assignments)

  def find_isomporhism(graph,subgraph):
  assignments=[]
  possible_assignments = [[True]*graph.n_vertices for i in     range(subgraph.n_vertices)]
  if search(graph,subgraph,asignments,possible_assignments):
   return assignments
  return None
```

here: [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537716/how-to-partially-compare-two-graphs). I do not have the skills to transform this into Matlab, if you have them , i would really appreciate if you could share your code when you're done.